# Why does Gtk.Dialog response signal spits 2 arguments instead of 3?

Tags: python, gtk3, glade, pygobject

I am trying to learn Python and PyGObject, so I have written a simple program that adds user inputted two numbers and shows the result and created the user interface using Glade.

[image]

[image]

It has also an about dialog. However, whenever I want to process `response` signal coming from the `about_dialog`, which is given when I hit the Close button or the `x` in the window title, the interpreter gives `TypeError`.

Here is the relevant part of the [full code](http://pastebin.com/pLT2W9NC) which has the Glade file [here](http://pastebin.com/NNrWGpkN):

```
...
class GUI():
...
    signalHandler = {
            'on_main_window_destroy': Gtk.main_quit,
            'on_button_quit_clicked': self.on_button_quit_clicked,
            'on_button_about_clicked': self.on_button_about_clicked,
            'on_button_add_clicked': self.on_button_add_clicked,
            'about_response':self.about_response
    }
    self.builder.connect_signals(signalHandler)
...
    def about_response(self, widget, response_id, user_data=None):
    # self.about_dialog.destroy()
    print(widget, response_id, user_data)
    print('About dialog closed.')
....
```

When the function is below and when the user_data is set to labelresult Label object, which holds the addition result first_number + second_number, using Glade as it can be seen in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwFec.jpg) screenshot:

```
def about_response(self, widget, response_id, user_data):
```

Output of the below is:

```
print(self, widget, response_id, user_data)
Output: TypeError: about_response() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

When I make `user_data=None`, the output is:

```
(<__main__.GUI instance at 0xb6dd458c>,
<Label object at 0x99c393c (GtkLabel at 0x9aeaa28)>, -6, None)
```

Without setting the user_data in glade, the output is:

```
(<__main__.GUI instance at 0xb6d3e58c>,
<AboutDialog object at 0xa09711c (GtkAboutDialog at 0xa191040)>, -6, None)
```

So, it only changes the GtkDialog *dialog parameter. I cannot understand this, because as I can see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkDialog.html#GtkDialog-response), the signal `response` throws 3 parameters, however in this case, it throws only 2.

What is going on here, why does Gtk.Dialog response signal spits 2 arguments instead of 3?

Comment: That is a type of signal connection GObject allows, I think. Something along the lines of swapping the user data position with the normal parameters position and removing the emitter. Sincerely I have no idea how to fix this but I'm pretty sure it has something to do with Glade.